# Showing Jason Result data from for loop to view section

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Just want to know that the following thing can be done by using Javascript - Ajax call.

In my ASP.NET MVC web application, there are posts that load on the home page created by users.

So like a Facebook post, it shows the Employee Name, Department, and the post (image) that he posts in this system.

This data collected code I wrote in the ActionResult in Home Controller.

But seems when It loads, the page loading time is increased.

to reduce the loading time now I have written this Ajax call and I tried to collect the data and pass it to the section where the post shows.

This is the code

```
function Announcements() {
 
  try {
    $.ajax({
      url: '../Home/Announcements',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      data: {},
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.Success == true) {
 
          for (var i = 0; i < data.Announcements; i++) {
 
            alert("Annoncementsdadsa")
          }
 
          $("#Announcements").append(data.Announcements);
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
}
```

This is the JsonResult

```
public JsonResult Announcements() {
  try {
    DateTime twoDaysAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
 
    List < NewsShareViewModel > smcNews = new List < NewsShareViewModel > ();
 
    smcNews = (from n in db.NewsShare join e in db.CreateEmployee on n.Created_By equals e.Id join d in db.CreateDepartment on e.DepId equals d.Id where n.CreatedDate > twoDaysAgo select new NewsShareViewModel {
      Id = n.Id,
        UserName = e.EmpName,
        Department = d.Department,
        Message = n.Comment,
        UserId = n.Created_By,
        CreatedDate = n.CreatedDate.ToString()
    }).ToList();
 
    return Json(new {
      Success = true,
        Announcements = smcNews
 
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    return Json(new {
      Success = false, ErrorMessage = ex.Message
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Here I'm returning the `UserName`,`Department`, `Message`, `UserId`, `CreatedDate`.

Those data are in the `data.Announcements` set and I want to pass the data to this view section.

```
@foreach (var item in RsmcNews) { <div class="card card-widget">
   <div class="card-header">
     <div class="user-block">
       <img src="@Url.Action(" RetrieveImage","UserProfile", new { id=@item.UserId })" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" onerror="this.src='/Addons/dist/img/Userdefault.jpg'">
       <span class="username">
         <a href="#">@item.UserName</a>
       </span>
       <span class="username">
         <a href="#">@item.Department</a>
       </span>
       <span class="description">Shared publicly - @item.CreatedDate</span>
     </div>
     <!-- /.user-block -->
     <div class="card-tools">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
         <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
       </button>
     </div>
     <!-- /.card-tools -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.card-header -->
   <div class="card-body">
     <h5> @item.Message </h5>
     <img class="img-fluid" src="@Url.Action(" RetrieveNews","NewsShares", new { id=@item.Id })" width="600" height="400" onerror="this.src='/Addons/dist/img/Userdefault.jpg'" sizes="50">
   </div>
 </div> 
}
```

So what I did earlier was in the `ActionResult` Index , I collect the data and pass it to the session. And from the session I pass it to `RsmcNews` variable and loaded on above section.

So want to know how to do the same with the Ajax Result.Summary of this is,  Now Already data are there on the `data.Announcements` and need to know how to pass it to the section by separating `UserName` , `Department` etc

Comment: it is much easier to return a partial view  with data and render it in a div. It will take one javascript line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may access data members under Announcement like `data.Announcements[i].UserName` and `data.Announcements[i].Department`

You will need to use `data.Announcements.length` instead of `data.Announcements` in the for loop

You may create a new div for output

```
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

And update the view from ajax function

```
function Announcements() {

    try {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Home/Announcements',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.Success == true) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Announcements.length; i++) {
                        var card = $(".card").clone().appendTo($("#outputDiv"));
                        $(card).find(".username a").text(data.Announcements[i].UserName);
                        $(card).find(".description").text("Shared publicly - " + data.Announcements[i].CreatedDate);
                        $(card).find(".card-body h5").text(data.Announcements[i].Message);
                    }

                    $("#Announcements").append(data.Announcements);

                }
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** As mentioned in comment, You can also use a partial view for loading the data.

First, Controller pass the model to the partial view

```
public ActionResult Announcements() {
  try {
    DateTime twoDaysAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
 
    List < NewsShareViewModel > smcNews = new List < NewsShareViewModel > ();
 
    smcNews = (from n in db.NewsShare join e in db.CreateEmployee on n.Created_By equals e.Id join d in db.CreateDepartment on e.DepId equals d.Id where n.CreatedDate > twoDaysAgo select new NewsShareViewModel {
      Id = n.Id,
        UserName = e.EmpName,
        Department = d.Department,
        Message = n.Comment,
        UserId = n.Created_By,
        CreatedDate = n.CreatedDate.ToString()
    }).ToList();
 
    return PartialView("YourPartialViewName", smcNews);
 
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    return Json(new {
      Success = false, ErrorMessage = ex.Message
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Make a partial view, get the data from Model

```
@model List < NewsShareViewModel >

<!-- Model equals to smcNews passed from Controller -->
@foreach (var item in Model) { 

  <div class="card card-widget">
   <div class="card-header">
     <div class="user-block">
       <img src="@Url.Action(" RetrieveImage","UserProfile", new { id=@item.UserId })" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" onerror="this.src='/Addons/dist/img/Userdefault.jpg'">
       <span class="username">
         <a href="#">@item.UserName</a>
       </span>
       <span class="username">
         <a href="#">@item.Department</a>
       </span>
       <span class="description">Shared publicly - @item.CreatedDate</span>
     </div>
     <!-- /.user-block -->
     <div class="card-tools">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
         <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
       </button>
     </div>
     <!-- /.card-tools -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.card-header -->
   <div class="card-body">
     <h5> @item.Message </h5>
     <img class="img-fluid" src="@Url.Action(" RetrieveNews","NewsShares", new { id=@item.Id })" width="600" height="400" onerror="this.src='/Addons/dist/img/Userdefault.jpg'" sizes="50">
   </div>
 </div> 

}
```

Display the partial view inside a div using `.html()`

```
function Announcements() {
 
  try {
    $.ajax({
      url: '../Home/Announcements',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      data: {},
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.Success!=null && data.Success == false) {
            console.log("Error: " + data.ErrorMessage);
        } else {
            $("#Announcements").html(data);
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
}
```